# Authorizing users for POST requests

Tags: php, php5, laravel

I've to authorize some users to do POST requests from their CMSs in order to create a new resource on my database. I've to send a JSON response containing the status of the response (successful or not), and on failure, send an array of the errors.

To not continuously repeat the `return` statement (i.e. `return response->json($response)`), I decided to use `goto`. Is it good or bad?

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function sendRequest(Request $request){
        $rules = [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            //other rules
        ];

        // Initialize response array
        $response['success'] = false;

        // Validate the input
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()){
            $response['errors'] = $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();
            goto send_response;
        }

        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $user = UserAuth::where('username', $username)->first();

        // Check if user exists
        if (null === $user){
            $response['errors']['username'] = 'Invalid Username';
            goto send_response;
        }

        // Check if password matches
        if (!Hash::check($password, $user->password)){
            $response['errors']['password'] = 'Invalid Password';
            goto send_response;
        }

        // other code here, at the end set $response['success'] to true

        send_response: 
        return response()->json($response);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `goto` unless you got a very good reason to do it. You don't. That's the beginning and end of it.

Comment: So it's better to repeat return statement?

Comment: Passing arguments and chaining functions keeps your code logical and readable. That's by far a better approach, yes.

Comment: [`if (null === $user){ ... } elseif (!Hash...`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see much thing to review, except `goto`.

## Code style...

...is OK.

I will suggest `functions` to be no more than 10-15 lines, unless you doing something that can not be separated, such preparing parameters for SQL database or things like this.

## `goto` issue

You should avoid `goto` at all costs. Remember in `PHP` there are operators such `break 2`, here is an example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i)
   for($j = 0; $j < 100; ++$j){
      // do something
      if ($some_condition)
         break 2; // exit two loops at once.
   }
```

In your case, I would suggest to do two functions, and instead of `goto`, use `return`. I can not be sure if this code will work, but this is the idea:

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{

    private function prepareResponse_(Request $request){
        $rules = [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            //other rules
        ];

        // Initialize response array
        $response['success'] = false;

        // Validate the input
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()){
            $response['errors'] = $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();
            return $response;
        }

        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $user = UserAuth::where('username', $username)->first();

        // Check if user exists
        if (null === $user){
            $response['errors']['username'] = 'Invalid Username';
            return $response;
        }

        // Check if password matches
        if (!Hash::check($password, $user->password)){
            $response['errors']['password'] = 'Invalid Password';
            return $response;
        }

        // other code here, at the end set $response['success'] to true

        return $response;    
    }

    public function sendRequest(Request $request){
        $response = prepareResponse_($request);

        return response()->json($response);
    }
}
```

Please note, many people (me excluded) will not like `return` in the middle of `function`.

Anyway if you do it this way, readability will be much better than with `goto`.